# what is $\int_{\gamma}\frac{2}{(z+2)^2}dz$ with $\gamma(t)=t+it\sin(\frac{\pi}{t})$ for $t>0$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Again a question about integration. Consider the integral $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{2}{(z+2)^2}dz,$$where $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\gamma(0)=0$ and $\gamma(t)=t+it\sin(\frac{\pi}{t})$ if $t>0$. I first tried to compute this integral by using the formula $$\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=\int_0^1f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt,$$where $f(z)=\frac{2}{(z+2)^2}$, but this are very ugly computations. Therefore my question is: Is there a possibility to compute this integral with methods from complex analysis (a version of residue theorem or maybe a cauchy-formula), or is the only way the get an result to determine $\int_0^1f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$?

Best

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus also has a complex version. If $F$ is holomorphic on $U$, and $\gamma$ is a path in $U$, then $(F\circ \gamma)'(t) = F'(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma'(t)$.

Comment: Is there a typo here or why didnt you just write $1$ instead of $\sin(\pi/2)$?

Comment: thanks a lot!! This was a typo! it should be "t" instead of "2". Can I still use the fundamental therem of calculus in the same way  now?

Comment: ok thanks. the fundamental theorem of calculus is useful here.